# Can I use a variable as a generic-indicator?

Tags: java, generics

Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to correctly formulate my question.

But I think with an example it becomes clear what I want to know:

I want to create an instance of a generic class. But i don't know the types of the class yet.
So instead of this:

```
Foo<Type1, Type2> foo = new Foo<>();
```

i wanto to do something like this:

```
Class<? extends Type> type = getExpectedType();
Foo<Type1, type> foo = new Foo<>();
```

I've already tried this and it doesn't work. But is something similar possible?

Comment: Note that there *are* some ways to achieve results *similar* to this with clever use of method type parameters. But to be able to tell if this applies in your case we'd need to know the underlying problem that you're trying to solve. This is effectively an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I think you misunderstand what generics are: they simply instruct the compiler to insert casts for you (and otherwise check that types are consistent). If you can't write something with explicit casts, you can't do it with generics.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible in Java, because type variables are not expressions. More concretely, Java has [Type Erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure), meaning that these types don't actually exist during runtime, they are replaced by the compiler with up-casts and down-casts from, and to `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the type at runtime, you must keep it in a field, and pass it to the constructor:

```
public Foo(Class<Type2> type2) {
    ...
    this.type2 = type2;
}
```

then:

```
Class<? extends Type> type = getExpectedType();
Foo<Type1, ? extends Type> foo = new Foo<>(type);
```